# Kusto Heartbeat ok but not all servers report Network Data

Tags: kql

I am new to Kusto and checked with that if all SQL Servers report back

```
Heartbeat
| where Computer like "SQL"
```

which showed all servers are connected. But this query only reports one server

```
let StartDate = format_datetime(now(-2d), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
let EndDate = format_datetime(now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
let StartDateTime = strcat(StartDate, " 00:00:00");
let EndDateTime = strcat(EndDate, " 23:59:00");

Perf
| where Computer like "SQL"
| where ObjectName == "Network Adapter" 
| where CounterName == "Bytes Total/sec" 
| where TimeGenerated between(todatetime(StartDateTime) .. todatetime(EndDateTime))
| project TimeGenerated , Computer , CounterName , InstanceName, CounterValue/1024/1024
| order by Computer
```

for other performance counters all servers report back. Only for this I can see only one server in the report. Any Idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your first query runs over all the data, your second query has filters on the TimeGenerated column, and I assume that this is what explains the difference. If you have evidence to show otherwise, please share.

By the way, instead of the 4 `let` statements that you have in your second query, you can write the following 2 instead:

```
let StartDateTime = startofday(ago(2d));
let EndDateTime = endofday(now());
```

Comment: thanks for that. Was not aware that these are two queries